# How do I center buttons with a div?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code and I am trying to center all the inputs within the div.

**Here are the CSS Snippets:**

```
#mainCalc label {
    display: inline;
    width: 8em;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 1em;
        float: left; }

#mainCalc input {

    display: inline;         
    float: left; }

#mainCalc br {
    clear: left;
```

**Here is the HTML Snippet:**

```
<div id="mainCalc">
  <input type="button" id="dollar" value="Dollar" />
  <input type="button" id="quarter" value="Quarter" />
  <input type="button" id="dime" value="Dime" />
  <input type="button" id="nickel" value="Nickel" />
  <input type="button" id="refund" value="Refund" /><br />
  <label for="amount">$</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" /><br/>
  <input type="button" id="coke" value="Coke" />
  <input type="button" id="dietCoke" value="Diet Coke" />
  <input type="button" id="mountainDew" value="Mountain Dew" />
  <input type="button" id="drPepper" value="Dr. Pepper" />
  <input type="button" id="rootBeer" value="Root Beer" />
  <input type="button" id="water" value="Water" /> <br /><br />
</div>
```

Comment: Did my answer work? Please tick/upvote if so to let others know. Else, let me know if it didn't, so I can delete it! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the inputs a width, and then you need to remove the float and add margin: 0 auto.

```
input{
width: 200px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
}
```

**Working example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/DYgnU/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
#mainCalc {
  text-align: center;
}
```

And remove the `float: left;` from `#mainCalc label` & `#mainCalc input`

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ivaxus/1/edit)

Comment: @user2101459 Great! Remember it's always nice to up vote answers that help you out...

Comment: @user125697 Wow indeed buddy, that's too bad. These situations should really change...